# java JInternalFrame: is it possible to make it overflowing out of parent?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jinternalframe

I want to have one main window, and inside that window should be child windows, which are draggable, resizable etc. If I use just JFrames or JDialogs, it gives me many problems about the stacking of the windows. When the main window has focus, the child windows shouldn't move to the background.
This can be so-so fixed by listening to window events and bringing the child windows to front again, but now I get even more problems, for example popup boxes and other prompt dialogs are not stacked in the right order.
My solution is to use JInternalFrame for the child windows, but the disadvantage is, that they are clipped by the parent container.
Here's an example (just from internet). You see the clipping of internal frames:

[image]

My question is: is it possible to make them visible outside the parent component, so the overflow is visible.
The final goal of the GUI is to get something like photoshop. Windows which are independent on the screen, but which will never go to the background of its main window (parent)

Comment: And are there any other solutions, without JInternalFrame?

Comment: What I think you're looking for is a stye of "tool" window, I had it in the back of my head that you could do this, but I can't find any informaiton

Comment: Believe it or not, I'm just changing my code to use a JToolBar, and it works!

Comment: <faceplam> should have thought of that -> probably was what I was thinking about :P